# Jquery slider auto again after finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slider

I´m new in Jquery and I need to help with this. I have Jquery image slider on the web page with rotation of few different images with timer 3000 per each image - they still repeat. Under the slider I have simple loader bar - based on other color hidding div with animation from left to right with the same timer 3000. Simple. But problem is, that this animation run only once and images rotate constantly. So question is, how can I make my loader bar with "reload" animation after timer is up? Like this - http://www.designbash.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/animated-loading-bar.gif

**My JQUERY**

```
function playslider(){
    var hidden = $('.colorSlide2');
    hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, 3000).addClass('visible');   
}   
playslider();
```

**My CSS**

```
.colorSlide2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    left:-100%;
    height: 5px; 
    background: #f8e508;
}

.colorSlide1 {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 5px; 
    background: #254b8b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$.fx.interval = -10;
function playslider(){
    var hidden = $(".colorSlide2")
    , reset = hidden.css("left");
    return hidden.animate({"left":"0%"}, 3000, "linear", function() {
     $(this).css("left", reset);
     return playslider()
    }).addClass("visible");   
}   
playslider();
```

```js
$.fx.interval = -10;
function playslider(){
    var hidden = $(".colorSlide2")
    , reset = hidden.css("left");
    return hidden.animate({"left":"0%"}, 3000, "linear", function() {
     $(this).css("left", reset);
     return playslider()
    }).addClass("visible");   
}   
playslider();
```

```css
.colorSlide2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    left:-100%;
    height: 5px; 
    background: #f8e508;
}

.colorSlide1 {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 5px; 
    background: #254b8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colorSlide1">
    <div class="colorSlide2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great, but when I change tab on browser and then I come back to the site with slider and loading bar, loading bar have some delay in comparation with images slider. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks!